# Where does the poll.id come from?

Tags: python, django

I'm studying the [DjangoTutorial03](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/), and don't quite understand where the `id` from `poll.id` comes from.

`poll.question` I get it, it's one of the attributes of class `Poll` in `models.py`. But not so much for `poll.id`. Is it an attribute inherited from `models.Model`? I'm not sure because I searched for `self.id` in both `base.py`&`__init__.py` from `/django/db/models/` and nothing showed up. (is it the right place to search for?)

Comment: It is because of the line `poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)`, I believe.

Comment: Try reading [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/) - *"An `id` field is added automatically, but this behavior can be overridden. See [Automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` field is automatically created for your model if you don't provide any other field with `primary_key=True` keyword argument. A good practice when dealing with primary keys is to use `pk` attribute, as opposed to `id`, because `pk` is an alias to the real primary key field be it `id`, `my_id`, or anything else - `poll.id` and `poll.pk` are both the same.

The behaviour is caused by the `Options` class  ([here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/options.py#L175)) which is what you get when you access `_meta` attribute, and it's attributes are derived from `Model.Meta`.